# sourcetree doesn't appear Authenticate

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree and I want to connect it with my GitHub repository. So I normally wanna use "push" for pushing my works to repository but It doesn't show me a authenticate pop up window. and it keeps showing this paragraphs:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false \
    -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags \
    --set-upstream origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

I maybe wrote wrong password yesterday. And I cannot fix it.
How can I fix it?

I am using MacOS, there are many solutions for windows but I cannot find it for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be to shift your URL from https (which does involve the "credential.helper=sourcetree") to SSH, provided you have [setup a public key in your BitBucket account](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html).
Preferably one without a passphrase for your private key, at least for testing.

The other test would be to keep your HTTPS URL for the remote, and see of you can switch to the system Git (instead of the embedded Git) in SourceTree, and make sure you have:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```